# Format credit card date MM/yy to MM/dd/yyyy

Tags: java, date, datetime-format, localdate

I have method that can take 2 different types of date formats:

- **MM/YY** (credit card expiration date)
- **yyyyMMdd** (funding expiration date)

`Credit card` expiration date is considered expired on the last day of that month. So, if cc date is May, 2017 (05/17), this cc is considered expired on 31th of May.

Funding expiration date will expire on the day it says it expires. So, if I am looking at it on the same day, it should return TRUE as funding has expired.

This is my code:

```
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.util.Date;

public static boolean dateHasExpired(String dateInput)
{
     LocalDate d = LocalDate.now();
     LocalDate dateParsed = null;

     if (dateInput.contains("/"))
     {
          int iYear = Integer.parseInt(dateInput.substring(dateInput.indexOf("/") + 1));
          int iMonth = Integer.parseInt(dateInput.substring(0, dateInput.indexOf("/")));
          int daysInMonth = LocalDate.of(iYear, iMonth, 1).getMonth().maxLength();

          dateInput = iMonth+"/"+daysInMonth+"/"+iYear;
      }
      else
      {
          dateInput = ConvertDate(dateInput, "yyyyMMdd", "MM/dd/yyyy");
      }

      DateTimeFormatter dateTimeFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MM/dd/yyyy");
      dateParsed = LocalDate.parse(dateInput, dateTimeFormatter);
      return d.compareTo(dateParsed) <= 0;
 }

public static String ConvertDate(String dateValue, String currentFormat, String requiredFormat)
{
     SimpleDateFormat inFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat(currentFormat);
     SimpleDateFormat outFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat(requiredFormat);
     String outDate = "";

     try
     {
         java.util.Date date = inFormatter.parse(dateValue);
         outDate = outFormatter.format(date);
     }
     catch (ParseException e) {
         ErrorLogger.logError  ( e );
     }
     return outDate;
 }
```

Does anyone know of better way of doing this?

I also noticed `LocalDate` doesn't account for `Leap Year`, so Feb 2015 has 29 days, just like Feb 2016, so my `daysInMonth` will not be a good number.

Looks like Date is more tollerant than LocalDate when it comes to year being yy and month 5 for month of May.

Comment: java8 periods...

Comment: Instead of `int daysInMonth = LocalDate.of(iYear, iMonth, 1).getMonth().maxLength();`, do `int daysInMonth = LocalDate.of(iYear, iMonth, 1).lengthOfMonth();`.

Comment: With @GriffeyDog’s suggestion, you will get leap years correct. `.getMonth().maxLength()` gave you the longest length that month can have, for February that’s 29 days. `.lengthOfMonth()` gives the actual length in the year in question, which is what you need.

Comment: FYI, the troublesome old date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), and `java.text.SimpleTextFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes. See [Tutorial by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `java.time.YearMonth` class, which contains a method that returns the last day of the respective month (and also takes care of leap years):

```
public static boolean dateHasExpired(String dateInput) {
    LocalDate today = LocalDate.now();
    LocalDate dateParsed = null;

    if (dateInput.contains("/")) {
        // parse credit card expiration date
        YearMonth ym = YearMonth.parse(dateInput, DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MM/yy"));
         // get last day of month (taking care of leap years)
        dateParsed = ym.atEndOfMonth();
    } else {
        // parse funding expiration date
        dateParsed = LocalDate.parse(dateInput, DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyyMMdd"));
    }

    // expired if today is equals or after dateParsed
    return ! today.isBefore(dateParsed);
}
```

With this code (considering that **today** is **May 02, 2017**):

```
System.out.println(dateHasExpired("04/17")); // true
System.out.println(dateHasExpired("05/17")); // false
System.out.println(dateHasExpired("06/17")); // false
System.out.println(dateHasExpired("20170501")); //true
System.out.println(dateHasExpired("20170502")); // true
System.out.println(dateHasExpired("20170503")); // false
```

Note that `atEndOfMonth()` method takes care of leap years, so these will also work:

```
System.out.println(dateHasExpired("02/15"));
System.out.println(dateHasExpired("02/16"));
```

I've added a `System.out.println(dateParsed);` in `dateHasExpired` method, just to check if the date is being parsed correctly. And the output for the dates above are (respectively):

```
2015-02-28
2016-02-29
```

And `dateHasExpired` returns `true` for both, as expected.

Comment: Good answer, but much better to pass a desired/expected time zone `ZoneId` to that `LocalDate.now` call. Otherwise you are depending implicitly on the JVM’s default time zone, so your results may vary (not good!). A **timezone is crucial to determining a date**. For any given moment the date varies around the globe by zone.  `LocalDate.now( ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" ) )`

Comment: @BasilBourque Good point, there's a lot to improve in this code, like using a `Clock` to make the code more testable,  error handling when the date input isn't in the correct/expected format and so on. I've just focused on the OP's main problem (parse the input and check if it's expired), but you're right. Thanks!